# The type or namespace name 'LAD' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Hello I have an ASP web application runs on C# as its backend that I'm trying to get running but the webpage (ran locally on my box) gives me the error message. Now the namespace the webapp is trying to reference is "using LAD.CDD.NSJ;" which are located in the App_Code folder.

The name of the files are Common.cs, Email.cs, Data.cs, and User.cs.

They all have a namespace call LAD.CDD.NSJ within the code. The previous programmers didn't make those files into a dll and just kept it as a .cs file. I'm trying to use these files for another project but keep getting that error message.

Comment: Are these .cs files added to your web app now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `App_Code` folder is a special folder in ASP.NET. ASP.NET will compile the types `App_Code` into an assembly which is actually separate from your web application assembly. This means, when you try and use those types from your backend code (e.g. an MVC controller), it is unable to resolve the type because those types will have a `Build Action` set to `Content`. With that build action, the file will not be included in the compilation of your main application.

What I would recommend doing, is ditch using `App_Code` because simply changing the build action to `Compile` won't stop ASP.NET dynamically compiling an `App_Code` assembly, so you end up with ambiguous types (i.e., the runtime doesn't know whether to use the type compiled into your main application assembly, or the dynamic App_Code assembly.

Move those files to another location, and set the Build Action (in Properties) to `Compile`.

Comment: I was looking at that and thinking maybe that could be part of the issue but I really don't know enough to know if that made a difference. It's pretty incredible that you narrow done to the exact issue, I'm impress. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If I move the files, where do you recommend me moving it too? Any folder besides the App_Code Folder?

Comment: Web Applications shouldn't care what your folder structure is (outside of using the special ASP.NET folders). Common practice these days is to use a `Models` folder, but I often feel that doesn't always describe that types contained within.