# Class file doesn't compile outside of App_Code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

I am using Visual Web Developer Express 2010 edition.
I have chosen "New Website" (and not New Project) to build a website.
My project is targeted for .NET 2.0

I have a class file which I originally created under the `App_Code` folder. I instantiated an object of the class in my `default.aspx.cs`

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
```

This compiles fine. However, the moment I deploy it on my remote IIS Server, it gives a compilation error when I invoke the remote website from my browser.

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So I found this SO Question here - [The type or namespace name 'LAD' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504767/the-type-or-namespace-name-lad-could-not-be-found-are-you-missing-a-using-dir)

It says that I shouldn't put the class file into the App_Code directory. It asks to put it in a diff place and set the Build Action (in Properties) to Compile. I couldn't find a Build Action in Properties in "MS Visual Web Developer 2010" - so I had to skip that step.

So just I deleted it from App_Code and recreated it in the root folder. Now my project doesn't build at all - I get the same error on the build phase itself.

> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have a strong feeling my MyClass.cs doesn't get built at all. What do I do? How do I tell the IDE to build it?

Comment: I would recommend using newer .NET version. 2.0 is **VERY** out of date! Also, IMHO it is better to create a new Web Project than Web Site and is the modern way to create sites as you can then simply deploy the binaries rather than the .cs files.

Comment: @Belogix - I have to do it this way for various reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Follow this step:

```
1) Right click on your class file in App_Code folder.
2) Click on properties.
3) Change Build Action to Compile
4) Build your App.
```

Check now it works.

Comment: 2 things 1) My class is not inside the App_Code folder - I have written why in my question 2) When I right click on my class, I don't have a 'Build Action' property.

Comment: No, you need to right-click on the `.cs` file and then on the pop-up context menu click **Properties**. Then on the properties window there will be an item named "Build Action". Or you can select the `.cs` file and press [ALT]+[ENTER] to view the Properties window.

Comment: You have moved your file outside App_Code. So,Check for public attribute. **public** class MyClass. Is this missing? And Change Namespace of your class, remove App_Code from it.

Comment: @Belogix - I am using "Visual Web Developer 2010 Express" - I have only 2 properties - File Name & Full Path

Comment: Check for public attribute. public class MyClass. Is this missing? And Change Namespace of your class, remove App_Code from it.

Comment: @HarshilRaval - I don't have a public attribute - but my class starts as `public partial class` - I think my problem is that this class file doesn't get compiled at all.

Comment: property is disabled not able to change it

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of website project, now with web application project you will be able to compile it outside of app_code folder

Comment: So does that mean that website project cannot have classes other than those in *.aspx.cs files?

Comment: @user93353 yes but you must put it in app_code then build your solution

Comment: If I put in app_code and build my solution - it works with F5. But doesn't work when I deploy it - that is explained in my question - that's the reason I pulled it out of App_Code. So does this mean that a website project cannot have classes outside of those in *.aspx.cs if it needs to be deployed on a IIS Server?

Comment: Im able to do it , with .net 4 , Im not sure what is the issue with your project, but you can put all your myClass code in a DLL, then use it

Comment: When you say `I'm able to do it with .net4` - do you mean you are able to remote deploy the website project with classes in your app_code. I cannot and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504767/the-type-or-namespace-name-lad-could-not-be-found-are-you-missing-a-using-dir says you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: is remote deploy different from publishing via FTP?

Comment: No idea - all I want to do is build locally but deploy on a IIS server in a different machine - I do it through Copy WebSite (through Http and frontpage extensions, I think)